# _SecTrustEvaluate linking error with Google Cardboard Unity3d SDK

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am trying to run the demo project that comes with the Unity3d package for Google cardboard, but I keep getting this error when I build in xCode.

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from:
      l155 in libvrunity.a(GTMSessionFetcher.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am running Unity 5.2.0f3 and Xcode 6.4.  The only things I have in my project are the CardboardSDK and the demo project both downloaded from here: https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity

Has anyone run into this problem before or know how to fix it?!

Comment: The answer below seems to be useful, if it fixed your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 22):

You need to add the `Security.framework` in order for it to build.

Comment: @SeloDeveloper you should accept this as a correct answer